# Как найти в тексте все несоответствующие символы данному регулярному выражению

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как найти на PHP в тексте все символы, не соответствующие данному регулярному выражению

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_~!$^().-]+$|^[а-яА-ЯёЁ0-9_~!$^().-]+$/isu
```

Например, есть строка `login41;23`. Как можно получить несоответствующий символ `;`?

Comment: Вот так - `/[^\w~!$^().-]/u`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew а если например не соответствующих символов больше чем один? login;№н гин4123

Comment: `preg_replace` находит все вхождения по умолчанию, `preg_replace('/[^\w~!$^().-]/u', '', $string)` сработает. Можно, конечно, `+` добавить: ``preg_replace('/[^\w~!$^().-]+/u', '', $string)``. Не суть.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew все супер то что нужно! Только почему то пробел в данном варианте не находит? http://i.imgur.com/A3IEYWU.png

Comment: [Всё находит](https://regex101.com/r/9p9su6/1). См. https://3v4l.org/Eg8RL. Что вам нужно? `preg_match_all`  или `preg_replace`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew мне нужно чтобы я получил в строке все эти не соответствующие символы, чтобы потом перебрать foreach каждый из символов. Preg_match тестировал то что нужно вроде

Comment: `if (preg_match_all('/[^\w~!$^().-]+/u', 'login;№н гин4123', $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}`? https://3v4l.org/8dJli

Comment: да все супер спасибо огромное! оформите решение я подтвержу правильный вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать *отрицающий (негативный) символьный класс*,

```
if (preg_match_all('/[^\w~!$^().-]+/u', 'login;№н гин4123', $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
// array(2) {  [0]=> string(4) ";№"  [1]=> string(1) " " }
```

См. [пример работы кода онлайн](https://3v4l.org/8dJli).

Обратите внимание, `\w` находит все буквы (и русские, и английские, и другие, так как здесь использован модификатор `u`), цифры и знак подчёркивания, а в отрицающем символьном классе, соответственно, находит все символы, отличные от приведённых выше.